# Problem with For Loop and Base Class Pointer which points to a derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm slightly perplexed. In my int main() I have created two std::unique_ptr, one which points to the parent class "User" and another one that points to the derived class "Admin". I subsequently std::move() these two std::unqiue_ptr to a std::vector of std::unique_ptr. I then pass the std::vector to a stand-alone function which will be able to iterate through the collection. Because I'm coming at this from the base class pointer in the for-loop I am unable to access the AdminFunction(). Why is this? Is there a solution to what I'm trying to achieve without creating an overloaded function? I really hope this makes sense. Sometimes is so hard to explain-code related problems.

```
// Polymorpism.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
class User {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string password;
public:
    std::string GetName() { return name; }
    std::string GetPassword() { return password; }
    void BasicUserFunction() { std::cout << "Basic user function\n"; }
};

class Admin : public User {
private:
public:
    void AdminFunction() { std::cout << "Admin function\n"; }


};

void DisplayPrivileges(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<User>>&users) {
    for (std::unique_ptr<User>&user : users) {
        user->BasicUserFunction();
        user->AdminFunction();
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<User>ptrAdmin = std::make_unique<Admin>();
    std::unique_ptr<User>ptrUser = std::make_unique<User>();
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<User>>users;
    users.push_back(std::move(ptrAdmin));
    users.push_back(std::move(ptrUser));
   
    
   
   
}
```

Comment: Of course you cannot, `User` simply does not have any `AdminFunction` method and that is all the compiler can see in the loop. There is no duck-typing like in python, all non-virtual calls are resolved at compile-time.

Comment: Apparently there is a way according to one answer. What's your thoughts on this?

Comment: My though is there is something wrong with the design itself - your interface support all `User`, yet you require `Admin` functionality. What do you expect to happen for the second, non-admin, user?

Comment: I'm moreover experimenting.

Comment: Okay, nothing wrong with it, but it makes the question harder to answer properly. The bottom line is the name resolution for a method is always compile-time thing. If you want to call `Admin` methods, you have to have at least `Admin` objects. You can use `static_cast` and hope for the best or `dynamic_cast` with virtuals as in the other answer. Another way is to involve templates to save on manually overloading the function for each vector type.

Comment: Your solution worked as well Quimby. Greatly appreciate your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [`dynamic_cast()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), like so:

```
void DisplayPrivileges(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<User>>&users) {
    for (std::unique_ptr<User>&user : users) {
        user->BasicUserFunction();

        auto admin = dynamic_cast<Admin *>(user.get());
        if (admin) {
            admin->AdminFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this requires that the base class has at least one virtual method,

Comment: It might be a good idea to note, that this requires at least one virtual method to work as the author does not use them yet in his code.

Comment: I've even applied virtual.

Comment: @GeorgeAustinBradley Make any virtual method in `User` class.

Comment: I have! It's saying "auto" isn't allowed here in my compiler - Visual Studio 2019 for Windows 10 Education. Do you have a resolution for this?

Comment: Oh, that. That is because declaring variables in `if` statements is C++17 feature. I believe VS does not enable it by default, not sure how to change it, try googling. Or you can replace the if with `auto admin = dynamic_cast<Admin *>(user.get()); if(admin!=nullptr)`.

Comment: I have it in C++ 17. That's very strange.

Comment: I hope the edited code now runs fine in your compiler. Thanks to everyone pointing out the problems!

Comment: IT ACTUALLY WORKED! Thanks so much!